# sql query that finds a number of type %xyxy at the end.. for eg: 92834646, 838717474

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to all the numbers of xyxy type in the end. Like 869930**7676** or 981622**4343**. There are thousands of numbers in my database. I need a simple sql query to search these numbers which are of pattern xyxy at the end. I am using php (codeigniter framework) and mysql.

Comment: How are your numbers stored?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you provide your table, or you can simply the data type you used for Number

Comment: Use ANSI SQL modulo, e.g `WHERE MOD(column_name, 10000) = 7676`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I am using mysql with php.

Comment: @PM77-1 : Sorry but i don't get you ? It's stored in a mysql db table obviously. Are you asking something else ?

Answer (score 2):

If that column is of an integer type, you could do something like this ("NumbersTable" is your table, "value" is the column containing the numbers to check)

```
select * from NumbersTable
where value % 100 = (value/100) % 100
```

`value % 100` gets the last two digits
`(value / 100) % 100` gets digits 3 & 4 (from the end)

**EDIT**
As per the comment by jarlh: the `%` is the SqlServer operator for the modulo function. Replace with the operator or function that is valid for your database.

If the column has a varchar type instead of integer, you could do a similar thing: isolate the last two characters and the next two and compare. You will need some substring function (in Sqlserver `RIGHT()` will be useful).

Comment: Product specific answer, and no dbms specified. ANSI SQL has `MOD()` instead of `%`.

Comment: I am using mysql and it's a varchar field.

Answer (score 0):

*Edited, according to the pertinent comment from @jarlh: below is the MySql (and other common SQL implementations) expression, followed by the ANSI SQL one.

You can adapt it depending on your DBMS own capabilities.*

The following assumes `target` is the name of the column where you look at.

I suppose that `target` is of `INT` type or something equivalent, so we must at first cast it into a string format:

```
-- this is for MySql and most other implementations:
CAST(target, VARCHAR)
-- this is for standard ANSI SQL:
CAST (target AS VARCHAR)
```

Then having a string we can get its interesting parts for what you're looking for:

```
-- this is for MySql and most other implementations:
SUBSTR(CAST(target, VARCHAR), -2)
-- and
SUBSTR(CAST(target, VARCHAR), -4, 2)
--
-- this is for standard ANSI SQL:
SUBSTRING (CAST (target AS VARCHAR) FROM CHAR_LENGTH (CAST (target AS VARCHAR)) -2 FOR 2)
-- and
SUBSTRING (CAST (target AS VARCHAR) FROM CHAR_LENGTH (CAST (target AS VARCHAR)) -4 FOR 2)
```

Finally your entire search query might look like:

```
-- this is for MySql and most other implementations:
SELECT * FROM `yourTable`
WHERE SUBSTR(CAST(target, VARCHAR), -2) = SUBSTR(CAST(target, VARCHAR), -4, 2)
-- report from above for ANSI implementation...
```